# Google Analytics: Connect AdWords Keyword with Event

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have set up a Google AdWords campaign with various keywords. In order to evaluate the effectivity of each keyword, I want to track each keyword against an event I have set up. The event fires when a visitor sends a contact form in order to book a trip.

Like this I can find out the conversion rate of every keyword. How would I go about this?

Furthermore, is using an event to track Keyword conversion rates the correct way to go about this or is there something smarter?

Thanks so much!

Thierry